# Java: replacing a new file

Tags: java

I draw an image on a panel by using `BufferedImage`, and now I want to export that image.

But how can I detect if the new file is created or replace the old one? right now my output is:

```
old filename: image.jpeg

new filename: image.jpeg.jpeg
```

How can I do it?? I put a detect code after the file is created, using `createNewFile` method, but it doesn't seem to work :(

This is pattern that do the saving, user can choose various types of image (bmp, jpeg ...):
`imageFile` is `File`

```
private void saveImage(){
        JFileChooser savefile = new JFileChooser("~/");
        savefile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);//Chose file only
        savefile.setFileFilter(new pngSaveFilter());//Save in PNG format
        savefile.addChoosableFileFilter(new jpegSaveFilter());//Save in JPEG format
        savefile.addChoosableFileFilter(new bmpSaveFilter());//Save in BMP format
        savefile.addChoosableFileFilter(new gifSaveFilter());//Save in GIF format
        savefile.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        int returnVal = savefile.showSaveDialog(null);//Show save dialog
        String EXT="";
        String extension="";
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            imageFile = savefile.getSelectedFile();
            extension = savefile.getFileFilter().getDescription();
            if (extension.equals("JPEG file images *.jpeg,*.JPEG")) {
                EXT = "JPEG";
                imageFile = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".jpeg");
            }
            if (extension.equals("PNG file images *.png,*.PNG")) {
                EXT = "PNG";
                imageFile = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".png");
            }
            if (extension.equals("Bitmap file images *.bmp,*.BMP")) {
                EXT = "BMP";
                imageFile = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".bmp");
            }
            if (extension.equals("GIF file images *.gif,*.GIF")) {
                EXT = "GIF";
                imageFile = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".gif");
            }
            try {
                if(imageFile != null){
                    topViewImagePanel.drawToSave();
                    System.out.println(imageFile.createNewFile());
                    //ImageIO.write(topViewImagePanel.getSavingImage(), EXT, imageFile);
                  // the code detection is below
                    if (imageFile.createNewFile()){
                        int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Image existed! Replace?", "Warning!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                        if (value == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                            imageFile.delete();
                            ImageIO.write(topViewImagePanel.getSavingImage(), EXT, imageFile);
                        }else if (value == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You fail to check for the return value of `imageFile.delete()`: it may fail!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(imageFile.exists())
```

Do a simple check to see if a file already exists or not.

Comment: In Java 7, you would use `Files.exists()`

Answer (score 1):

Don't append file extension manually to the file name.
It is already present in the absolute path.

To handle files already present, use else clause of

```
if (imageFile.createNewFile())
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7, use the new API:

```
if (imageFile != null) {
    final Path path = imageFile.toPath();
    if (Files.exists(path)) {
        int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            "Image existed! Replace?", "Warning!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
             if (value == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                 Files.delete(path);
    }
    ImageIO.write(topViewImagePanel.getSavingImage(), EXT,
        Files.newOutputStream(path));
}
```

Also, as to your original question:

> I put a detect code after the file is created, using createNewFile method, but it doesn't seem to work :(

This is normal, you call `.createNewFile()` *twice*:

```
System.out.println(imageFile.createNewFile()); // <-- CALL 1
//ImageIO.write(topViewImagePanel.getSavingImage(), EXT, imageFile);
// the code detection is below
if (imageFile.createNewFile()){ // <-- CALL 2
```

It will always fail the second time!

Comment: It throws a Illegal Argument Exception because the Image is null

Comment: What image do you mean?

Comment: Well there is the error at the line ImageIO.write so i think the image is null, ImageIO just can't write a null image to a file

Comment: Uhm, that is another problem then... Sorry, but while I know how to do file I/O, images are not my forte ;)

Comment: I think the operations should be similar. If the ImageIO is null, then there is something wrong in that statement. But thank you anyway :)